# How to simplify expression with "int", modulus, and division?

Tags: algorithm, perl, math

The below script calculates the time difference in decimal number, but I get a rounding error, so I guess it is because of my very bad conversion at the end.

**Question**

Something tells me, that the expression can be simplified, but what are the math rules in this particular situation, when I have `int`, modulus and division?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print f("9:00", "16:45");

sub f {
    my $t1 = shift @_;
    my $t2 = shift @_;

    my $m1 = $1*60+$2 if $t1 =~ m/(\d\d?):(\d\d?)/;
    my $m2 = $1*60+$2 if $t2 =~ m/(\d\d?):(\d\d?)/;

    my $h = int(($m2-$m1)/60);

    return $h + ($h*60+$m2-$m1)%60/60;
}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: You shouldn't bake your own time math code. What happens when time1 is  1:20am and time2 is 3:20am and the date is 3/9? The actual difference in time is 1 hour. Look into a time module; like the DateTime suite: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime

Comment: "The actual difference in time is 1 hour" - well that depends which country you're in. Not all countries have daylight saying time and the ones that do don't all change on the same date (and I don't know any that change it on 3rd September!)

Comment: @DaveCross I believe Oesor meant March 9th. Having read one of your comments on another post about "having been burnt once too often by people who think that MM/DD/YY is an acceptable format for dates," I found this humorous :)

Comment: Oh, I know what he meant. I was making the subtle point that in an international forum like SO, a date format of M/D (or, indeed, D/M) is just going to be confusing to most of the readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already correctly calculated `$m1` and `$m2` as minutes elapsed since midnight. So why not return the time difference in fractional hours as simply:

```
return ($m2 - $m1) / 60.0;
```

As far as the "math rules," maybe it will help to look at your `return` versus mine and see why they are equivalent (ignoring rounding):

```
$h + ($h * 60 + $m2 - $m1) % 60 / 60
```

Notice that `($h * 60) % 60` is zero, so this term essentially drops out, leaving:

```
$h + ($m2 - $m1) % 60 / 60
```

Now think about how `$h` was calculated: it is the quotient of `($m2 - $m1)` divided by 60, *dropping the remainder* (because of `int()`). On the other hand, `($m2 - $m1) % 60` *is* exactly the remainder of this division. So the expression above is essentially just adding the remainder fraction, which you dropped from `$h`, back in. Therefore it has the same result as

```
($m2 - $m1) / 60
```

Comment: That is a very good point. Is is possible to come from my complicated expression to yours? Or can algorithms not be compared to equations?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes You may have commented just before I updated my post to include some steps showing why the two are equivalent? It can be proven algebraically; the last step about "adding the remainder back in" could be written more rigorously but I tried to convey the idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) to do simple date/time calculations:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $pattern = '%H:%M';

my $start = Time::Piece->strptime('09:00', $pattern);
my $end   = Time::Piece->strptime('16:45', $pattern);

my $diff  = $end - $start;
print $diff->hours;
```

#### Output:

```
7.75
```

Note that `$diff` is actually a [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) object.

Comment: I assumed the OP was doing this as some sort of exercise, but if not, this answer is absolutely the better solution for production use. Avoid reinventing the wheel wherever possible, *especially* when it comes to date/time calculations, which are notoriously sticky subjects.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to use `Time::Piece`, but I assume this is some sort of exercise.

In Unix, all dates are converted to seconds since *the epoch*. It makes it easy to do arithmetic on stuff when everything is in the same units. Therefore, I would convert the times to minutes, do your operations, then convert the time back to hours and minutes. That would mean you need to subroutines. One to convert the time from hours and minutes to minutes. And one to convert from minutes to hours and minutes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $time1 = "9:50";
my $time2 = "16:45";

my $time1_in_minutes = convert_to_minutes( $time1 );
my $time2_in_minutes = convert_to_minutes( $time2 );

my $diff_in_minutes = $time2_in_minutes - $time1_in_minutes;

say convert_to_hours( $diff_in_minutes );


sub convert_to_minutes {
    my $time             = shift;

    my ($hours, $minutes) = split /:/, $time;
    my $total_minutes = ( $hours * 60 ) + $minutes;
    return $total_minutes;
}

sub convert_to_hours {
    my $minutes         = shift;

    my $hours = int $minutes / 60;
    $minutes = $minutes % 60;
    return sprintf "%d:%02d", $hours, $minutes;
}
```

By breaking down the work into two subroutines, you can easily see what is going on. Plus, you have a lot more flexibility. What if I gave you times it took for me to run a marathon, and I want the average time? You could use the same two routines. What if I gave you the time I spent at work each day, and I wanted a total? Again, you could use the same subroutines.

And, because it's much easier to see what's going on, it's easier to correct errors that crop up when you program. Even better, because the operations are clean, I can start adding features. For example, it would be nice to check my input. In my `convert_to_minutes` subroutine, I might want to make sure that the hours and minutes are valid. That there's a colon in the middle. That the minutes aren't greater than 60.